# Set all BigDecimal operations to a certain precision?

Tags: java, math, rounding, bigdecimal, floating-accuracy

My Java program is centered around high precision calculations, which need to be accurate to at least 120 decimal places.
Consequentially, all non-integer numbers will be represented by BigDecimals in the program.

Obviously I need to specify the accuracy of the rounding for the BigDecimals, to avoid infinite decimal expressions etc.
Currently, I find it a massive nuisance to have to specify the accuracy at every instantiation or mathematical operation of a BigDecimal.

Is there a way to set a 'global accuracy' for all BigDecimal calculations?
(Such as the `Context.prec()` for the *Decimal* module in python)

Thanks

---

Specs:
Java jre7 SE
Windows 7  (32)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**(Almost) Original**

Not as simple, but you can create a [`MathContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html) and pass it to all your `BigDecimal` constructors and the methods performing operations.

**Revised**

Alternatively, you can extend `BigDecimal` and override any operations you want to use by supplying the right `MathContext`, and using the rounding version of `divide`:

```
public class MyBigDecimal extends BigDecimal {

      private static MathContext context = new MathContext(120, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

      public MyBigDecimal(String s) {
           super(s, context);
      }
      public MyBigDecimal(BigDecimal bd) {
           this(bd.toString()); // (Calls other constructor)
      }
      ...
      public MyBigDecimal divide( BigDecimal divisor ){
           return new MyBigDecimal( super.divide( divisor, context ) );
      }
      public MyBigDecimal add( BigDecimal augend ){
           return new MyBigDecimal( super.add( augend ) );
      }
      ...
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: I'm actually having some difficulty using the class extension. If I have 2 BigDecimals representing "1" and "3", both of which have scale set to 120...
Dividing "1" by "3" still produces a non-terminating decimal, even if I assign the result a scale of 120 as well!
(Which was what I was originally trying to avoid; extra parameters to math operations).

Comment: I think that you can fix that by similarly overriding the `divide` method for your class.

Comment: I really don't want to write my own Decimal module, I just want to understand why BigDecimal is being so uncooperative./

Comment: It's trying to be as exact as possible, which means trying to never round unless asked to. The divide override is simple, you just wrap the rounding `divide`. Now that I think about it, it would be a good idea to override other operations are using to make sure that they are returning an instance of your class and not a regular `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Yep. There's no need to me to even override a constructor than is there? (By default, won't a string passed to the constructor be converted to a BigDecimal of the exact value of the string?)

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to override (well, implement, technically you never override a constructor) the string constructor. Constructors don't get inherited automatically.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use my factory approach!  @StephenC's comments on it are correct - the `MathContext` passed to the constructors does not influence later operations, only the conversion performed in the constructor.

Comment: I'll be honest, I now have no ideas on how to implement this. Can somebody provide some example code? (show constructor and divide override methods?)

Comment: I see.
I'm still unsure why I need to superclass the constructor. I don't need exactly 120 decimal places of accuracy, just at least 120.
Should I then only re-implement the divide function, the only concern being non terminating decimals, and have the rest accurate to whatever it turns out to be?

Comment: Unfortunately, you will still need to superclass the constructor if you want to use a `number.divide(otherNumber);` syntax, because you need `number` to be of type `MyBigDecimal` and not `BigDecimal`. Another option is to just forget about subclassing and write a `static BigDecimal divide( BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b ){ a.divide(b,context);};` function and use it instead of the one provided.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been thinking :) Thankyou sir!

Comment: @trutheality - "Superclassing" a constructor is bad terminology.  Constructors are not inheritable in Java ...

Answer (score 4):

Create a `BigDecimalFactory` class with static factory methods matching all constructors that accept `MathContext` - except that the `MathContext` instance is inside the factory and statically initialized  at startup time.  Here's a fragment:

```
public class BigDecimalFactory {
    public static BigDecimal newInstance (BigInteger unscaledVal, int scale) {
        return new BigDecimal (unscaledVal, scale, _mathContext);
    }

    // . . . other factory methods for other BigDecimal constructors

    private static final MathContext _mathContext = 
        new MathContext (120, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
}
```

Comment: This won't work ... if I read the javadoc correctly.  The primary reason is that the constructor you are using uses the `MathContext` for the conversion only.  It is not attached to the resulting `BigDecimal` object.

Comment: That means that the precision constraint won't apply to operations performed on the `BigDecimal` instances created with the factory ... unless you supply the `MathContext` as an argument to to relevant operation.

Comment: Argh!  You're right.  I mentioned your comments in one of the other threads in this post so that people know.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to set a 'global accuracy' for all BigDecimal calculations?

No.

You'll have to create a wrapper class that has a `MathContext` as an extra attribute.  It will need to:

- use this `mc` for each mathematical operation that would otherwise use the default semantics, and
- create and return another wrapped instance each time the wrapped operation returns a regular instance.

(As a variation, you could implement a 'global' `MathContext` using a static, but you'll still need to use wrappering to ensure that the `mc` is used.)

(Extending `BigDecimal` would work too, and that is arguable neater than a wrapper class.)

---

You said this in a comment:

> I really don't want to write my own Decimal module, I just want to understand why BigDecimal is being so uncooperative.

(Design questions can only be answered *definitively* by the design team.  However ...)

As with all complicated utility classes, the design of BigDecimal is a compromise that is designed to meet the requirements of a wide range of use-cases.  It is also a compromise between the competing meta-requirements (wrong word) of "powerfulness" and "simplicity".

What you have is a use-case that is not particularly well supported.  But I suspect that if it was well supported (e.g. with a global `MathContext` controlling everything or a `MathContext` attached to each `BigDecimal`) then that would introduce all sorts of other complexities; e.g. dealing with operations where there are two or more competing context objects to consider.  Such problems could be dealt with ... but they are liable to lead to "surprises" for the programmer, and that is not a good thing.

The current approach is simple and easy to understand, and if you need something more complicated you can implement it ... by explicitly supplying a `MathContext` for the operations that require it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class that extends `BigDecimal` and sets the precision automatically for you. Then you just use you that class.

```
public class MyBigDecimal extends BigDecimal {
      public MyBigDecimal(double d) {
           super(d);
           this.setScale(120, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
      }
      ...
}
```

Comment: This only works if the wrapper also wraps all of the BigDecimal operations that create a new instance.

Comment: This wont work. From the JavaDocs on 'setScale': "Note that since BigDecimal objects are immutable, calls of this method do not result in the original object being modified, contrary to the usual convention of having methods named setX mutate field X. Instead, setScale returns an object with the proper scale; the returned object may or may not be newly allocated." So calling it in the constructor won't do anything, at least in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper for BigDecimals, which will do this job:

```
 class BigDecimalWrapper {
     BigDecimal bd;   

     BigDecimalWrapper add(BigDecimalWrapper another) {
         BigDecimal r = this.bd.add(another.bd);
         r.setScale(...);
         bd = r;
         return this;
     }
     // and so on for other operations
 }
```

In this case you don't have to override all operation of BigDecimal (in extending case), just ones you use. It gives you control over all instances and doesn't force to follow BigDecimal contract.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create your own wrapper class that has your default MathContext like this full example:

In this example, I used the library (https://projectlombok.org)

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class BigDecimalFactory {

    //Seguindo a precisão máxima do PowerBuilder e Oracle Database
    public static final MathContext DEFAULT_CONTEXT = new MathContext(120 , RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    private static final BigDecimalFactory FACTORY = new BigDecimalFactory();

    private class SBigDecimal extends BigDecimal {

        public SBigDecimal(BigDecimal bdNumber) {
            super(bdNumber.toPlainString());
        }

        public SBigDecimal(String stringNumber) {
            super(stringNumber);
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.divide(divisor, DEFAULT_CONTEXT).stripTrailingZeros());
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor, MathContext mc) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.divide(divisor, mc));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal divideToIntegralValue(BigDecimal divisor) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.divideToIntegralValue(divisor));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal divideToIntegralValue(BigDecimal divisor, MathContext mc) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.divideToIntegralValue(divisor, mc));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal remainder(BigDecimal divisor) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.remainder(divisor));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal remainder(BigDecimal divisor, MathContext mc) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.remainder(divisor, mc));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal pow(int n) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.pow(n));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal pow(int n, MathContext mc) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.pow(n, mc));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal abs() {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.abs());
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal abs(MathContext mc) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.abs(mc));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal negate() {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.negate());
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal negate(MathContext mc) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.negate(mc));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal plus() {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.plus());
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal plus(MathContext mc) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.plus(mc));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal round(MathContext mc) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.round(mc));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal setScale(int newScale, RoundingMode roundingMode) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.setScale(newScale, roundingMode));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal setScale(int newScale, int roundingMode) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.setScale(newScale, roundingMode));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal setScale(int newScale) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.setScale(newScale));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal movePointLeft(int n) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.movePointLeft(n));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal movePointRight(int n) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.movePointRight(n));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal scaleByPowerOfTen(int n) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.scaleByPowerOfTen(n));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal stripTrailingZeros() {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.stripTrailingZeros());
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal min(BigDecimal val) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.min(val));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal max(BigDecimal val) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.max(val));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal ulp() {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.ulp());
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal add(BigDecimal augend, MathContext mc) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.add(augend, mc));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal subtract(BigDecimal subtrahend) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.subtract(subtrahend));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal subtract(BigDecimal subtrahend, MathContext mc) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.subtract(subtrahend, mc));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal multiply(BigDecimal multiplicand) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.multiply(multiplicand));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal multiply(BigDecimal multiplicand, MathContext mc) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.multiply(multiplicand, mc));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, int roundingMode) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.divide(divisor, scale, roundingMode));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.divide(divisor, scale, roundingMode));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor, int roundingMode) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.divide(divisor, roundingMode));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor, RoundingMode roundingMode) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.divide(divisor, roundingMode));
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal add(BigDecimal augend) {
            return new SBigDecimal(super.add(augend));
        }
    }

    public BigDecimal internalCreate(String stringNumber) {
        return new SBigDecimal(stringNumber);
    }

    public static BigDecimal create(BigDecimal b) {
        return FACTORY.internalCreate(b.toString());
    }

    public static BigDecimal create(String stringNumber) {
        return FACTORY.internalCreate(stringNumber);
    }

    public static BigDecimal create(Long longNumber) {
        return FACTORY.internalCreate(longNumber.toString());
    }

    public static BigDecimal create(Integer doubleNumber) {
        return FACTORY.internalCreate(doubleNumber.toString());
    }

    public static BigDecimal create(Double doubleNumber) {
        return FACTORY.internalCreate(doubleNumber.toString());
    }

}
```

Test:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class JavaTeste {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        //1) With your own BigDecimal
        BigDecimal b1 = BigDecimalFactory.create("100");
        BigDecimal b2 = BigDecimalFactory.create("25");
        BigDecimal b3 = BigDecimalFactory.create("13");
        System.out.println(b1.divide(b2));
        System.out.println(b1.divide(b3));


        //2) Without your own BigDecimal
        MathContext mathContext = new MathContext(38, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        BigDecimal b01 = new BigDecimal("100", mathContext);
        BigDecimal b02 = new BigDecimal("25", mathContext);
        BigDecimal b03 = new BigDecimal("13", mathContext);
        System.out.println(b01.divide(b02));
        System.out.println(b01.divide(b03, mathContext));

        //3) And this just not work
        BigDecimal b001 = new BigDecimal("100");
        BigDecimal b002 = new BigDecimal("25");
        BigDecimal b003 = new BigDecimal("13");
        System.out.println(b001.divide(b002));
        System.out.println(b001.divide(b003));

    }

}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use the BigDecimal setScale function!

```
BigDecimal db = new BigDecimal(<number>).setScale(120, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); (or down)
```

Comment: I would still have to perform this at every instantiation of a BigDecimal.